# Best method to archive data using Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, archive

I have a two tables chart and chartHistory which has similar table structure

```
chart_id   NUMERIC(9,0)
chart_ref_id  NUMERIC(9,0) NOT NULL
chart_property VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL
chart_value  VARCHAR2(100)
```

The entries in chart needs to be stored into the chartHistory table, when we get new property/value pairs for chart reference id.

I am planning to implement it using Hibernate in the following way

Get the list of values from CHART table using the chartReferenceId

```
List<Chart>  chartList =  chartDao.findChartByVisitRef(chartReferenceId);
```

*( named query : findChartByRef = from Chart chart where chart.chartReferenceId=:chartReferenceId)*

Use the retrieved list and build a chartHistoryList using the values from chartList and call the Hibernate method saveAll

```
chartHistoryDao.saveAll(chartHistoryList);
```

Once saved, remove the existing entries from the CHART table.

```
chartDao.deleteAll(chartList);
```

Build a newChartList for the new entried received, and do a hibernate saveAll

```
chartDao.saveAll(newChartList);
```

As you can see this executes four queries ie. for retrieving old records, saving them into the archive table, deleting the old entries and inserting the new values.

I would like to know whether there is a better way to implement this? Something of the sorts insert into .. (select from... ) would be more efficient I guess? Please advice.

Comment: Have a look at [Hibernate Envers](http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/index.html). I think it could suit your needs, it's typically used for saving auditing history of Hibernate entities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the envers/audit module of Hibernate which handles all this for you automatically.

The main problem with envers/audit right now is to find the documentation. [Envers](http://www.jboss.org/envers) (the original module) is supposed to be merged with Hibernate code since 3.5 but the [core documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/) doesn't mention anything about versioning or auditing even though InfoQ insists "[Hibernate 4.1 Released With Improved Auditing Support](http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/02/hibernate-4-1-released)"

So try the outdated documentation linked from the obsolete [envers](http://www.jboss.org/envers) page and hope for the best.

Disclaimer: I haven't used Hibernate or envers for years.